# React Frontend Post/Put Requests to Django Backend Permission Problem

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have full CRUD on my Django backend and am now trying to have full CRUD on my React frontend.

Successfully created the form and was able to assign values to a new post and console.log it. When I attempted to `post` to backend I first got a `403 (Not Allowed`, but then I changed my REST_FRAMEWORK from `'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'` to `'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'` and am now getting `405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

### Some Code

**Backend**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ]
}
```

**Frontend**

```
handleFormSubmit = (event, requestType, circuitID) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
        const description = event.target.elements.description.value;

        console.log(name, description)

        switch ( requestType ) {
            case 'post':
                return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/', {
                    name: name,
                    description: description
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            case 'put':
                return axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/${circuitID}/`, {
                    name: name,
                    description: description
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
```

**url patterns in app backend**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', circuit_list.as_view()),
    path('create/', circuit_create.as_view()),
    path('<pk>', circuit_detail.as_view()),
    path('<pk>/update/', circuit_update.as_view()),
    path('<pk>/delete/', circuit_delete.as_view()),


    path('workout/create/', workout_create.as_view()),
    path('workout/', workout_list.as_view()),
    path('workout/<pk>', workout_detail.as_view()),
    path('<pk>/update/', workout_update.as_view()),
    path('<pk>/delete/', workout_delete.as_view()),
]
```

**url patterns in Django**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/', include('circuit.api.urls'))
]
```

### What I have done

I have installed CORS so that's not my problem.

The console.log of name and description works so it's receiving the new input. I've changed the urls on the frontend and backend but that gives me more obvious errors of not being able to find the server.

I'm trying to find another way to grant permissions. I have tried including @permissions above the selected views, but it's still throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are sending `axios` requests to a wrong URL!

The line `return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/', {` will send a request to Django `/api/` URL, which is handled by `circuit_list` view. You should send your requests with `post` method to `http://localhost:8000/api/create` and for `put` methods to `http://localhost:8000/api/<pk>/update` and ..